# Asp.Net Website giving error when upgraded my server from 2.0 to 4.0

Tags: asp.net

This code is working fine on my local computer which has Visual Studio 2010 and it was 
working fine on .NET Framework 2.0  but when I upgraded my server from 2.0 to 4.0 
it is giving this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'staticpage_namespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 10: using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
>
> Line 11: using System.Data.SqlClient;
>
> Line 12: using staticpage_namespace;
>
> Line 13:
>
> Line 14:

Can any any body help?

Here is the code which i am using for class in  App_code folder:--

```
namespace staticpage_namespace
{       
  public class Staticpage
    {
    ......  
     public SqlDataReader InsertHome()    
        {
          SqlDataReader dr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(configclass.DbConn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "InsertHome");

            return dr;
   }


        public Staticpage()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code for my webform:-

```
using staticpage_namespace;


public partial class _Default1 : System.Web.UI.Page    
{ 

}
```

Comment: Did you add <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"> in Web.Config?

Comment: Yes, I have included this line in my web.config file

Comment: Try adding in app_code folder or add reference to this namespace

Comment: can you explain your point a little bit more i am not able to understand it.

Comment: Does it give error when you compile or when you Run the website? it is quite strange problem

Comment: I have added the reference in my webform by using this line........using  staticpage_namespace;      But this does not solve my error.....

Comment: It works fine on my local machine, but when i upload it to the server it give this error.......

Comment: If you have access to online folder try copying all the folder and run locally that way you can see what it going on. other than that there should not be any problems

Comment: I have copied same files which are working fine there from my local machine to the server, but at server it does not works it gives compiletime error......

Comment: I am sorry i have no idea why it is not working. It should work.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply......I will search about it, more on google......

Comment: Do post your solution once you have solved so others will be able to take pointers#

Comment: Yeah sure, i will post it once i will solve it......

Comment: Have a read of this answer http://forums.asp.net/post/4912548.aspx - does that help?

Comment: hey,thanks kevin for ur reply....http://forums.asp.net/post/4912548.aspx  this forum helps to solve my problem.......

Answer (score 0):

this dosent look to me as a conversion isssue. your website depends upon some namespace named `staticpage_namespace` which isnt present make sure you have appropriate code files in the `app_code` folder and then try to convert again.

Comment: This is the code for my class used in App_code folder....namespace staticpage_namespace


{

  public class Staticpage

    {

    ......  

        public SqlDataReader InsertHome()

        {


            SqlDataReader dr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(configclass.DbConn, 


CommandType.StoredProcedure, "InsertHome");


            return dr;

   }


        public Staticpage()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }
    }
}

Comment: are you are sure there is no compilation error in this namespace.. try compiling only this namespace.. or compiling the website before conversion.

Comment: I have used This namespace in my class which is then used by the webform...........

Comment: hey,thanks kevin for ur reply....forums.asp.net/post/4912548.aspx this forum helps to solve my problem.......